# using underscore template in bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, underscore.js

I'm trying to put two column data in a bootstrap popover.  I'd want it to look like something like this:

```
Name: crystal
Created On: 1/1/2000
Modified On: 1/31/2000
Owner: Bob
```

I want to have space between ":" so it's a two-column layout.  This popover is shown in a kendo grid on hover over.  I show a basic popover for that grid with:

```
$('a.hasPopover').popover({
                placement: 'bottom',
                content: '??????????????????',
                template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-no-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            });
```

In my template for this row, I originally had this just to see if my popover and data were connected:

Details

This does work.  However, I'm not sure how (even if it's possible), to create a data-content template that would have divs for each of my columns and shove the data in.  So I was wondering how I can use templates in either the content field where I have all those ????, or how to format my data-content properly to have two columns.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a template. You can set the `html` option to true and set your html in the data-content attribute, like:

```
<a class="hasPopover" rel="popover" data-content="<div class='span1'>test:</div><div class='span1'>longer text gives a problem?</div><br><div class='span1'>test:</div><div class='span1'>value</div><br>">POPOVER</a>
```

javascript:

```
$('a.hasPopover').popover({
                placement: 'bottom',
                html : 'true',
                template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-no-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            });
```

Id this don't work. Try the `content` option. You can use this as a function to manipulate your data-content attribute like:

```
            content : function(){ return $(this).attr('data-content').toUpperCase(); },
```

Comment: How would I have access to the data from my grid (e.g. name, owner, createdOn, etc)?

Comment: My above comment is if I tried using the content: function in your last example.  I wasn't sure how to get to my ${name} or ${createdOn} values like in the data-content tag.

Comment: Can you add the code which constructs your javascript? It seems http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#fields-tbody the `tbody` object should contain the data. You can use this in the content function above.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is possible to use a template. Here's an example:

```
$('a.hasPopover').popover({
  placement: 'bottom',
  html: true,
  content: _.template('<h1><%= test %></h1>')({ test: 'Hello World '})
});
```